# python pandas creating additional rows evenly to get a full range

Tags: python, pandas

python 2.7 and pandas 0.16.
I have a dataframe that has an index of percentiles (10,25,50,75,90) and values at each percentile (see code below). I am trying to fill in the percentile numbers to have all values from 10-90 for each section (10, 11, 12, etc.) and interpolate the values using the pandas interpolate function. Is there a way to easily do this in pandas/python? The interpolating part is easy, but filling the gaps between percentiles is where I am stumped.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

percentiles = [10,25,50,75,90,10,25,50,75,90,10,25,50,75,90]
sections = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C']
values = [3,10, 16, 19, 30, 5, 12, 19, 25, 40, 1,5, 11, 13, 33]

df_percentiles=DataFrame(percentiles,columns=['percentile'])
df_percentiles['section']= sections
df_percentiles['value']= values
```

Comment: What is the output dataframe that you want?